# Añadir a Carrito de compras con react

Tags: reactjs, usestate

soy novato, tengo una duda. Estoy diseñando un ecommerce con react.
En la Home aparece cada producto con su info y el boton de carritos de compras con el siguiente codigo:

```
    const productosComprados =(producto)=>{
const productoRepetido = carrito.find((item)=> item._id === producto._id)

if (productoRepetido){
  setCarrito(carrito.map ((item)=> (item._id === producto._id? { ...producto, Cantidad: productoRepetido.Cantidad + 1}: item)))
}else{

  setCarrito ([...carrito, producto])
}
}
```

Funciona perfecto, el problema viene en que en cada cars puse el link MAS INFO se puede hacer clik y nos muestra mas fotos del producto y desde ahi se deberia poder agregar al carrito por lo que hice fue usar el useContext y el useState. Cuando hace click en el link pasa mediante el useState el dato del producto puntual a esa variable y al tenerlo en el useContext la puedo llamar de esta nueva pagina. Pasa que aveces funciona y a veces no.
Si use la misma formula que en la home no entiendo porque a veces lo toma y aveces no.

Comment: Agrega el código mínimo indispensable para reproducir el problema, con la porción de código que estás mostrando, solo se puede adivinar

Comment: Me es dificil saber que parte del codigo agregar...

Comment: fácil, cual es el código mínimo que necesitas para reproducir el problema? cual es el código necesario para que yo o cualquier otra persona pueda copiar el código y obtener el mismo error que tu?

Comment: Amigo esto es una zona de comentarios, no puedes debes poner el codigo aqui sino en la pregunta, mejor crea una nueva y agrega el codigo

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/609471/a-veces-funciona-y-a-veces-no-wtf-ecommerce-con-react