# A veces funciona y a veces no. Ecommerce con react

Tags: array, reactjs, card

soy novato y anteriormente formule la pregunta pero no fui del todo claro y especifico. Estoy desarrollando un ecommerce con react.
En la Home se presentan los productos cada uno en su Card y ahi tengo un boton que si quiere comprar lo suma al carrito de compras, eso funciona perfecto.
El problema viene cuando en cada card puse un link para poder ver mas fotos del producto y dentro de esa pagina tambien tengo un boton para adherir el
producto al carrito y he aqui el problema, a veces funciona a veces no. A veces tarda, como explique soy novato y creo el error viene por que deberia ser una funcion
asincronica porque para ver si me tiraba los datos cuando desde la home hacen clik en el link MAS INFO puse un console log para ver si traia los datos del producto y
a veces solo trae el array vacio sin el producto. Uso createContext para poder llamar los datos de cualquier componente, mi logica es que cuando hace el click en el link
de MAS INFO pase la info a una constante que uso con useState y ahi le asigno los datos del producto, que despues intento levantar desde el otro componente de MAS INFO.
PASO CODIGO:

CREATE CONTEXT:

```
const DataProvider = ({children})=>{
    const [productData, setProductData]=useState([]);
    const [carrito, setCarrito]=useState([]);
    const [info, setInfo]=useState([]);
    

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('https://tienda.paacu.repl.co/productos')
                          .then(res=> res.json())
                          .then(data => {
                          setProductData(data);
                          })
},[productData]);
    return (
        <dataContext.Provider value={{ productData,setProductData, carrito, setCarrito, info, setInfo }}>
            {children}
        </dataContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default DataProvider
```

DESDE LA HOME:

```
const Cards = () => {
   const { productData,setProductData, carrito, setCarrito, info, setInfo }=useContext(dataContext)
   const [search, setSearch]=useState("");

const productosComprados =(producto)=>{
const productoRepetido = carrito.find((item)=> item._id === producto._id)

if (productoRepetido){
  setCarrito(carrito.map ((item)=> (item._id === producto._id? { ...producto, Cantidad: productoRepetido.Cantidad + 1}: item)))
}else{

  setCarrito ([...carrito, producto])
}
}

const detalle =(producto)=>{
setInfo(producto);
console.log(info);

}

const filtrar =(e)=>{
  setSearch(e.target.value)
  }

let resultado=[]
if (!search){
  resultado=productData
}else{
  resultado= productData.filter((dato)=>
  dato.Producto.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase()))
 
}
    return(
        <>


<Flex justifyContent="center">
        <Stack  margin="25px" width="50vw">
  <Input
    isInvalid
    errorBorderColor='crimson'
    placeholder='¿Que producto deseas buscar?'
    autoFocus
    value={search}
    onChange={filtrar}
   
  />
</Stack>
</Flex>    



  <Flex margin="20px" wrap="wrap" justifyContent="center" gap="20px" >
    {resultado.map ((producto)=>(
        <Card maxW='sm' border="red 1px solid" width="25vw" shadow="25px solid" key={producto._id} >
  <CardBody display="flex" justifyContent="center">
    
    <Image  height="200px" 
      src={producto.Foto1.secure_url}
      alt='Green double couch with wooden legs'
      borderRadius='lg'
    />
    <Stack mt='6' spacing='3'>
      <Heading size='md'>{producto.Producto}</Heading>
      <Text >
       {producto.Descripcion}
      </Text>
      <Text color='blue.600' fontSize='2xl'>
       ${producto.Precio}
      </Text>

     <Link to={`/Imagenes`} onClick={()=>detalle(producto)} >Más info...</Link>
        
    
    </Stack>
  
  </CardBody>
  <Divider />
  <CardFooter display="flex" justifyContent="center">
    <ButtonGroup spacing='2'>
      <Button variant='solid' colorScheme='blue' onClick={()=> productosComprados(producto)}>
      <box-icon name='cart-add'></box-icon>
      </Button>
      
    </ButtonGroup>
  </CardFooter>
</Card>))}
</Flex>

        </>
    )
}

export { Cards }
```

DESDE LA PAGINA DE MAS INFO:

```
const Imagenes = () => {
    const { productData, carrito, setCarrito, info, setInfo }=useContext(dataContext)
    

 const expandirImagen=(imagen)=>{
    Swal.fire({
        imageUrl: imagen,
        imageHeight: 550,
        imageAlt: "Producto"
      });
 }

const productosComprados=  (info)=>{
    console.log(info);
    const productoRepetido =  carrito.find((item)=> item._id === info._id)

  if (productoRepetido){
   setCarrito(carrito.map ((item)=> (item._id === info._id? { ...info, Cantidad: productoRepetido.Cantidad + 1}: item)))
}else{

  setCarrito ([...carrito, info])
}}


    return(
        <>
        <Container className='contenedor1' fluid >
 <Container fluid >
    <Row>
    <Col xs={9} md={3} lg={2.5} >
    <Image src={info.Foto1.secure_url} className='Foto1 img-thumbnail img-fluid'  onClick={()=> expandirImagen (info.Foto1.secure_url)} rounded/>
    
        <p className='descripcionimagen'>Click en la imagen para agrandar</p>
    
    </Col>

    <Col xs={3} md={3} lg={1} className='fotos'>
    <Row >
    <Image src={info.Foto2.secure_url} onClick={()=> expandirImagen (info.Foto2.secure_url)} className='Foto2 img-fluid'/>
    </Row>

    <Row >
    <Image src={info.Foto3.secure_url} onClick={()=> expandirImagen (info.Foto3.secure_url)} className='Foto3 img-fluid' />
    </Row>

    <Row>
    <Image src={info.Foto4.secure_url} onClick={()=> expandirImagen (info.Foto4.secure_url)} className='Foto4 img-fluid'/>
    </Row>
    
    
    </Col>
 

    <Col className='conte2'>
        <Row>
    <h1 className='titulo-producto'>{info.Producto}</h1>
        </Row>


<Row>
    <h2 className='titulo-producto'>{info.Descripcion}</h2>
</Row>
<Row className='renglon'>

<Button variant='outline-warning'   className='boton-compra2'>
     <h2>{info.Precio}</h2>
      </Button>
      
</Row>

<Row className='renglon'>

<Button variant='outline-info'   className='boton-compra'>
      <box-icon name='cart-add' onClick={()=> productosComprados(info) } ></box-icon>
      </Button>
</Row>
    </Col>
    </Row>

</Container>

</Container>
        </>
    )
}

export { Imagenes }
```

Comment: ¿Este `console.log`, llega a ejecutarse?
```const detalle =(producto)=>{
setInfo(producto);
console.log(info);

}```

Comment: ¿En donde trae el array vacío en `Card` o en `Images`?, ¿ pasa cuando `search` es `truth/falsy` o en ambos casos?

Answer (score 0):

Yo no he tenido ningún problema con el carrito, me trae los datos bien. Solo he cambiado el *useEffect* de tu contexto porque tienes una dependencia (productData) que luego cambias en el mismo efecto lo cual modifica la dependencia, esto dispara el efecto el cual vuelve a cambiar la dependencia y así infinitamente, aquí hay algo de info al respecto: [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/prevent-infinite-loops-when-using-useeffect-in-reactjs/).

Queda así el useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://tienda.paacu.repl.co/productos")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setProductData(data);
      });
  }, []);
    
  console.log('cart: ', carrito)
```

Funciona tanto si se agrega el producto desde *Cards* o desde *MasInfo*

Comment: Primero que nada gracias por dedicarle tiempo a mi pregunta. Modifique lo que me decis pero sigue igual, a veces funciona y a veces no. sigo sin entender  porque.

Comment: No me deja porque tengo que tener 20 de reputacion para hablar ahi

Comment: Vi que me estoy equivocando con el uso de useState, por ser asincronico.